# How do I generate the UI component in angular 8 based on component?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 8.

After I login and the application will return a role access json.

I am wondering if it is possible to generate angular component based on the json.

The components are already built.

ROLE A:

```
{
   "component":"mainmenu",
   "displayname":"warehouse",
   "child":{
      "component":"submenu",
      "displayname":"dashboard",
      "child":[
         {
            "component":"items",
            "displayname":"approve"
         },
         {
            "component":"items",
            "displayname":"reject"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

ROLE B:

```
{
   "component":"mainmenu",
   "displayname":"warehouse",
   "child":{
      "component":"submenu",
      "displayname":"dashboard",
      "child":[
         {
            "component":"items",
            "displayname":"View"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is a sample UI of what i want to achieved.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "generate angular component?" You mean you want angular to automatically create a UI design for you? The look and feel? You can run `ng g c my-component` to have angular generate a component for you, but I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: it is more like based on the json, i wan to load my ui component based on it

Comment: Ok. How do you expect angular to know what you want the UI to look like for these JSONs?

Comment: so for example if i have another `"component":"mainmenu",
   "displayname":"Orders"` ignoring the json structure. i wan to have another menu to be displayed. I am looking at generating by component instead of by role. which will make role access assignment and validation easier.

Comment: You have to code that on your own. Converting JSON to HTML must be done using [angular components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a direct answer to your question because it needs more planning and coding which is more specific to your design. But I suggest you look at the
 [Angular Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) where you can refer as a starting point.